# Make column take the values from another column in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

My problem is that I'm creating a column that is meant to be the foreign key, however the issue appears before adding the FK constraint. Since it has only null values the first thing I would do is to give it the values of the column in another table it is supposed to refer.

I've seen a lot of answers on this site to similar question, even one for a question that seems to be 100% the same as mine, however, I always find the particular problem that such queries end up taking **only the first value** from the source and copying it on every row of the table being updated.

Entering the values with `INSERT (c1,c2,c3) VALUES(1,2,3)` wouldn't be reliable since it would be a pain to update it in practice given the case of the database becoming bigger.

This is the basic example I've encountered:

```
UPDATE Table1 set Table1.a = Table2.a
FROM Table2
 JOIN  Table2 on Table1.a = Table2.a
```

(I've tried it without inner join too)

There are many variations, but I end up with the same problem.

This is a work for school and we have to do exactly what I'm trying to do, so I can't  just use `INSERT` because it is obviously unreliable.

Comment: With unreliable, I mean it wouldn't be the proper way of doing it, since an INSERT query would be painful to perform for a big database/table. Currently, my teacher is using INSERT for this, but I know INSERT is meant to be used when you are trying to insert the first ''wave' of values in  a row.

Comment: you want to update a column of a table from another column by joining the same column. you know its like update x = x where x = x.

Comment: Your code snippets wouldn't change anything, because table1.a=table2.a already, so it doesn't make sense. Can you explain better what you are trying to acheive - give same data for table1 and table2 as they are now, and some sample data of what you want to end up with in table1.

Comment: No, please read. I want to give the NEW column I have just created in one table to get the values from the one it will refference. The INNER JOIN statemen is just there to show what I got from the other questions I looked at before asking one myself, I know it will do nothing as it is.

Comment: silly question, but is there a way to join these tables prior to the FK being added? that is how you would need to join the tables for the update statement above. If that is not possible, then the data would need to be reloaded, because there is no way to associate one record to another without a relationship of some kind.